# Magento 2: Use a custom controller as website root?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, routing

I'm building a little module on magento2 and I can currently access it at `mysite.com/test/mymodule`. I want to be able to access it at `mysite.com`.

How can I do that?

I've tried doing a URL rewrite in the admin panel but it didn't work, I either get the 'too many redirects' error when I put '/' as the request path, and nothing happens when I put '\' like another thread suggested. 
I've also searched how to do it by modifying my XML, with no success.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure default route from admin .

Go to Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> [ General ] -> Web -> Default Pages.

Here is configurations for home page.

Try to add your route as default route, or add your module content to Cms home page

[image]

Comment: That seems to work very well! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not add any redirect on it. It is called the Homepage by default.

You can do this work by 2 methods:

## Method 1:

You can configure default route from admin .

Go to **Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> [ General ] -> Web -> Default Pages.**

Here is configurations for home page.

Try to add your route as default route or add your module content to Cms home page

## Method 2:

You can follow the below steps to call data on Home page (Root)

1. First create block, controller & template file.
   According to this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html)
2. After that Call your module phtml file in the home page layout.
   You can Call Phtml file on CMS Page like [this](https://webkul.com/blog/call-phtml-file-cms-page-magento2/)

`{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\BlockClass" template="Vendor_Module::block_file.phtml"}}`

So after that Your custom module code will call on Root (homepage).

Comment: How can I find the path to my module ? this one (and the one in the link) aren't working

Comment: You will have to give the file path which you gave in the layout like this

`<block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Display" name="helloworld_display" template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::sayhello.phtml" />`

Comment: Found it, thanks ! This is going to be useful

Comment: @Badong If it is helpful for you please accept this answer.